# Derivative of $\arcsin(x)$ in $-1$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

I need to find the derivative $\arcsin'(-1)$. I know that $(\arcsin)'(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$. I also know that
$$f_{+}'(b)=\lim_{x \to b+}f'(x) \tag{1}$$
and that the right derivate is $+\infty$.

**But I need to calculate the right derivate without using equation (1).** Please help me how.

Thank You.

Comment: Why not plug it in?

Comment: It doesn't exist. Just replace $(-1)$ in the equation above

Comment: $\arcsin(-1)$ is a constant, so its derivative is $0$. The derivative of $\arcsin$ at $-1$ does not exist in the sense it's usually defined in the calculus book.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Yes, but I'm sure that the OP means $f'(1)$, where $f(x)=\arcsin(x)$.

Comment: Isn't it obvious that the value is an undefined $1/0$ case ?

Comment: Draw the graph of arcsin.  See that at the point $-1$, there is a vertical tangent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we have

- $$\arcsin(-1)=\frac{-\pi}{2}.$$
- $$\sin'(\frac{-\pi}{2})=\cos(\frac{-\pi}{2})=0.$$

thus

$x \mapsto \arcsin(x)$ is not differentiable at $x=-1$.

but, if you want,

$$\arcsin'(-1)=\frac{1}{\cos(\arcsin(-1))}=+\infty$$

Comment: "$x\mapsto \sin x$ is increasing" is not the best of statements, since the reason why $\lim\limits_{x\to -1^+}\arcsin'(x)=+\infty$ is actually the fact that $\sin(x)$ is **not** increasing in a neighbourhood of $\arcsin(-1)$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli To get $+\infty$ as limit.

Comment: The left limit of the derivative  $ \lim\limits_{x\to -1^-}\arcsin'(x)=-\infty$

Comment: @G.Sassatelli the left limit and the right limit are not equal. So $f'(a)$ doesn't exist, right ?

Comment: @papabiceps It is not defined at left $-1$.

Comment: Yeah you are correct @AbdallahHammam . The left limit values go to imaginary numbers. My bad

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = \sin x$ . Then $f'(- \pi/2)= \cos(- \pi/2)=0$. Therefore it is easy to see that

$ \lim_{x \to -1}\frac{\arcsin(x)-\arcsin(-1)}{x-(-1)}$ does not exist.

Hence the Conclusion: $\arcsin$ is not differentiable at $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

You have it right, you have $ x^2-1 $ vanishing in the denominator, so its derivative is $\infty.$ The graph has two  tangent lines parallel to y-axis at $ x= \pm 1$ which also confirms your result. Its inverse has slope zero there.

Comment: I know it is correct, but I need an another way to prove it :-)